# OneToMany relationship and join with where clause

Tags: sql

Does anyone have a really good example where there are two tables with a OneToMany relationship where doing a left join with Table B as the target would be less useful than just doing a left join with table A as the target using the WHERE clause.

```
Table A (ManyToOne with Table B)
Pk
Number
Fk

Table B
Pk
IsActive
```

I mean, I can write a join like so

```
select * from TableA as a left outer join TableB as b on b.pk=a.fk where b.isActive=false and a.Number < 15
```

instead of writing

```
select * from TableB as b left outer join TableA as a on b.pk=a.fk where b.isActive=false and a.Number < 15
```

I mean, if I was supporting joins on a noSQL system, when would I ever need to support the second one because someone could not just rewrite it as the first one above AND is there a good use case for this so I can wrap my head around when it would be used?

The reason I ask is in object query language, I am wondering if I ever need to support doing a where clause in this situation(or instead if I just disallow something like this)...

```
 select b from TableB as b left fetch join b.tableAList as a where b.isActive=true and a.xxxxx = something
```

but isn't that invalid since b has many a rows so a.xxxx is invalid as it is a list and could only really be a.size which would be count of the rows in the list of a rows for that b row.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your examples are effectively inner joins.

When you do a left outer join, the values in the second table are NULL.  Your WHERE clause is:

```
where b.isActive=false and a.Number < 15
```

NULL values will cause this to fail, removing all the "virtual" rows added from the second table.

If you really want a left outer join, then you need to include these in the ON clause rather than the WHERE clause.

In general, though, `A LEFT OUTER JOIN B` and `B LEFT OUTER JOIN A` are quite different.  The first keeps all rows in A, with the matching rows from B (or NULL values if there is no match).  The second keeps all rows in B, with all the matching rows from A (or NULL values if there is no match).

Comment: ah, I thought it would returns the null rows AND return the rows where b.isActive = true.  okay, so I would need to do where (a.fk = null || b.isActive = false) && a.Number < 15 to do that then

Comment: Or, alternatively, `coalesce(b.IsActive, false = false and a.Number < 15`.

Comment: If there's a PK-FK (primary key / foreign key) relationship between the tables and the join is on the PK-FK columns, there shouldn't be any entries in the FK table that don't match the PK table, so a LEFT JOIN with the FK table as the dominant table (LHS of join) should be pointless (the same as a regular join).  In the converse direction, there might be rows in the PK table with no corresponding row in the FK table; for that, the LEFT JOIN with the PK table as the dominant table might make sense.